# Why is the value from a static library function wrong?

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries

file a.c :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    double r = 0;
    r = call(10.0,2.0);
    printf("r:%lf\n",r);
    return 0;
}
```

Function call() is in a static library like:

file call.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

double call(double a,double b){
    double c;
    c = a + b;
    printf("c :%lf\n",c);
    return c;
}
```

The command that I used is

```
gcc -c call.c -o call.o

ar rcs libcall.a call.o

gcc -o a a.c -lcall -L.
```

So why is the result not 12? If I change the double type to int type, the result is 12.

Comment: If this is your whole code, does it compile? It doesn't have declaration of your `call` function

Answer (score 7):

Compile with warnings and the compiler will tell you why it's wrong.

You don't have a prototype for the function `call` so when you call it from main it gets an implicit `int` return type which isn't what it actually returns.

Answer (score 2):

When writing a C program, compile it with a C compiler. It really does solve a lot of problems.

```
gcc -c call.c -o call.o -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall
```